# How can pandas be scripted to slice rows from the previous day on a rolling basis?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a python/pandas script to analyze a continually updated CSV file. The script is intended to analyze only data collected on the previous day. In other words, on any given day my script must slice rows from the previous day. How might I go about this?

Most tutorials assume you already know the specific range dates you wish to slice, allowing you to use e.g. df.loc[2023-07-07:2023-07-07] to yield all rows on the 7th of July. In these approaches the dates selected do not vary.

However my script requires that the date of the rows being sliced continually varies as the script runs from one day to the next: e.g. on day 1 I require only rows from the 7th of July, but on day 2 I require only rows from the 8th of July, and on day 3 only rows from the 9th of July, ad infinitum.

The dataframe sourced from the CSV is indexed by time stamps. My hunch is that timedeltas and masks are involved in the solution of my problem, but I’ve not found a way to execute this in practice.

Thank you for your help

**Edit for clarification**

The source csv file contains a DATE column formated as DD-MM-YY and TIME column HH:MM. I combine these into pandas 64bit timestamps using the following lines of code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('/path/to/csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[['DATE','TIME']], date_format='%d-%m-%Y')

df.index = pandas.to_datetime(df.index)
```

When the df is printed, the index column is now lableled DATE_TIME and is (mostly) in the format YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:00

However, I can see some inconsistencies in the way pandas in interpreting dates from my CSV file: some are printed as YYYY:DD:MM, others appear to be YYYY:MM:DD. Clearly there's a problem in the way dates are being parsed. The plot thickens. Thank you so much for your advice - any ideas how to resolve this?

**Edit to answer my own edit**

When parsing dates, there is a difference between **%y** (which expects a two-digit year) and **%Y** (which expects a four-digit year). Correct date parsing for a CSV with two-digit years in the date column is:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('/path/to/csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[['DATE','TIME']], date_format='%d-%m-%y')
```

and NOT

```
df = pandas.read_csv('/path/to/csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[['DATE','TIME']], date_format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: If the dates are sorted, you don't need to know both ends: `df.loc['2023-07-07':]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice with only the start boundary:

```
# get yesterday's date
start = pd.Timestamp('today').normalize()-pd.DateOffset(days=1)

# slice from yesterday's rows on 
out = df.loc[start:]
```

Comment: This looks like an elogant solution – thank you. Unfortunantly the code is getting an error: “KeyError: Timestamp('2023-07-08 00:00:00')”.

The CSV file has separate time and date columns, which I turn into datetime objects in the pandas dataframe using:
df = pandas.read_csv('/path/to/csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[['DATE','TIME']], date_format='%d-%m-%Y')
df.index = pandas.to_datetime(df.index)

Could my approach here be part of the problem? Perhaps the timestamps are in the wrong format? - Many thanks for your ongoing advice.

Comment: Is your index a DateTime64Index? `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` should work. Please provide a reproducible example of the data as edit to your question. (Referring to an unknown file is not reproducible).

Comment: Edited as requested - thanks so much Mozway, you're certainly getting me close.